# Eyes in the contact point during follow-through?

Tags: football, technique, tennis, golf, follow-through

This [video (8min53s)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGMnuqKexG8&t=8m53s) mentions that eyes are always at the contact point even during the follow-through, I understand this so that the video generalises the observation to all ball games. I instructed my friend in golf to follow the ball during his shot and his shot seemed to become better but this instruction to follow the contact point during the follow-though. So

> **Where are eyes supposed to be during the follow-through in ball games? Do the eyes follow the ball during shots or do they follow the contact point during the shots?**

Comment: The eyes can't follow the ball off the racket: it's going too fast, but most players kind of try. Feeder is a prominent exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, prolong the time on the contact point during the follow-through.**

Follow-through is a repeating thing in ball games. Keeping your eyes on the contact point in the follow-through helps to keep you focused and determined during the shot, avoiding mistakes due to hesitance such as forgetting to look at the ball and looking too early to the target.

**[Article supporting eyes on the contact-point during the follow-through](http://darrengolsby.com/golf-swing-basics-keep-your-eyes-on-the-golf-golf-ball/3751)**

> More than these physical effects, the recent observations tend to go
>   **in favor of the mental benefits to control the head position and prolong the fixation of the contact zone to the entire duration of the follow-through.**
>
> **Fixation during the follow-through helps keep focus on the task at hand which leads to increased feeling and control.**
>
> Specifically, this control can impact the hitting response which in
>   the past was believed to be out of control because of visual
>   limitations.
>
> Fixation helps to control both the emotions and thoughts reducing
>   stress and anxiety, therefore increases self-confidence.